# Extracting image url as a string from inside a div class XPath

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

Im having some issue extracting some image urls from amazon with xpath.

The page im trying to extract the url is this one, as an example

[https://www.amazon.com/Touchscreen-Laptop-Tablet-Windows-Quad-Core/dp/B07FYX613Z/ref=sr_1_23/147-3050782-9544926?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1542390985&sr=1-23&keywords=gaming+laptop&refinements=p_36%3A-100000](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FYX613Z)

I have this:

```
<div id="ivLargeImage" style="height: 573px; display: block; opacity: 1; visibility: visible; cursor: zoom-in;"><img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81zqMok22fL._SL1500_.jpg" class="fullscreen" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 252px; height: 553px; width: 573px;"></div>
    <img src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81zqMok22fL._SL1500_.jpg" class="fullscreen" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 252px; height: 553px; width: 573px;">
```

My goal is to extract [https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81zqMok22fL.*SL1500*.jpg](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81zqMok22fL._SL1500_.jpg)

I am currently using the xpath

```
//div[contains(@id, "ivLargeImage")]/img/@src
```

Which actually gives me [https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81zqMok22fL.*SL1500*.jpg](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81zqMok22fL._SL1500_.jpg) when i check with XPath Helper

Problem is that, when i extract that information with

```
item['img0Product']= response.xpath('//div[contains(@id, "ivLargeImage")]/img/@src').extract()
```

No data appears in that variable.

EDIT: Added amazon links

Comment: Can you share URL of Amazon page?

Comment: Edited the question with the correct links

Comment: Amazon is constantly changing layouts and sends multiple layouts for AB testing which means you need multiple xpaths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can get required image with below XPath:

```
//div[@id="imgTagWrapperId"]/img/@data-old-hires
```

Try and let me know in case it doesn't work as expected

Comment: As you can see in the amazon site, there are several images to extract, what would be your recommendation to get all of the urls?

Comment: @Manuel, Do you mean you want all that images (thumbnails to the left from main image) in high resolution?

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to do that but I'm only being able to get one url

Comment: @Manuel , Those images are not present as DOM elements. All images' URLs can be extracted from `script` node that you can get with XPath `'//script[contains(., "ImageBlockATF")]/text()'`. Probably you will need regex to parse that script... You'd better submit new question regarding this new issue

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `extract_first()` instead of `extract()`?

`extract()` typically returns a selector list, not a single value.

Comment: Tried it out but extract_first() returns "none" in this case